# GetPreviewFrameASync Invalid parameter type

Tags: c#, uwp

I am working in UWP and trying to make the following tutorial example work. In summary i am trying to get a frame from a MediaCapture and display it to an Image UWP Control element.

```
 var previewProperties = _mediaCapture.VideoDeviceController.GetMediaStreamProperties(MediaStreamType.VideoPreview) as VideoEncodingProperties;
        VideoFrame videoFrame = new VideoFrame(BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8, (int)previewProperties.Width, (int)previewProperties.Height);
        var source = new SoftwareBitmapSource();

        var previewFrame = await _mediaCapture.GetPreviewFrameAsync(videoFrame);


        SoftwareBitmap previewBitmap = videoFrame.SoftwareBitmap;
        await source.SetBitmapAsync(previewBitmap);
        img.Source = source;
```

When the GetPreviewFrameASync function is execute i get a runtime exception reffering Invalid parameter type. Have anyone experiencing the same problem before and what was the cause of it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Turns out there was absolutely no problem with my code,but somehow the **CAMERA** was to blame for the error. Many others that ran my project had no issues and when I changed my camera everything was fine.If you are unlucky enough to experience the same problem try running it with another cam.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your segment code and reproduced your issue, the problem is you have not started previewing before `GetPreviewFrameASync` method executed. The following is the method of starting to preview.

```
private async Task StartPreviewAsync()
 {
     try
     {
         _mediaCapture = new MediaCapture();
         await _mediaCapture.InitializeAsync();
         _displayRequest.RequestActive();
         DisplayInformation.AutoRotationPreferences = DisplayOrientations.Landscape;
     }
     catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
     {

     }
     try
     {
         PreviewControl.Source = _mediaCapture;
         await _mediaCapture.StartPreviewAsync();
         _isPreviewing = true;
     }
     catch (System.IO.FileLoadException)
     {

     }
 }
```

For more please refer to [Basic photo, video, and audio capture with MediaCapture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/basic-photo-video-and-audio-capture-with-mediacapture). I have upload [code sample](https://github.com/ZhuMingHao/GetPreviewTest.git) to github. Please check!

Comment: First of all thank you a lot for your answer and your time!I had written the exact same code in my code and got the error I posted. I even tested your code sample at GitHub(by copying the xaml and cs because the project I downloaded needed me to install an SDK ), and the preview of the camera is ok like in mine, but when I click CapturePhoto I get the same exception every time "The parameter is incorrect". Do you have any idea what could cause this problem? Everything seems right. Thank you again in advance.

Comment: The code sample works fine in my side. Please try to update your [Windows 10 SDK](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk) version to 10.0.15063.468 for excluding sdk issue.

Comment: I did the updates and nothing changed. Then a friend mentioned maybe compatibility issues with the camera since it worked for him. It worked also for other people and then I changed my camera and worked for me. I dont have a clue what was wrong with my old camera since it perform all the previous MediaCapture tasks etc that I  wrote but anyway...problem solved.Thank you once again for your time :)